# How to map 2D/3D mixed scene in cocos2d-x

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x, game-engine

I am working on a game project where I am using both 2D and 3D objects in the game scene, but I am not able to map 2D coordinates with 3D coordinates,

How to convert 3D spaceNode to 2D spaceNode.In addition how can we get width and height of the 3D object, So I can manage the 2D sprites accordingly.

Thanks.